# Regex Lookahead - Separate sections

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

Suppose I have a text containing following (two) sections:

```
Section1
,111,
,222,
,333,
Section2
,444,
,555,
,666,
```

I want to match only the items from section one, e.g. 111, 222 and 333.
I tried something like: `,\d+,.*(?=Section2)` but, of course this is matching everything till Section2, and I'm not sure how to tell it to match separate groups. Note that Section1 can have more items than in the example above.

EDIT:
I now get what I want with ,\d+,(?=.*Section2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex `(?is)(?<=Section\d+)(.+?)(?=((Section)|($)))` for separate values into sections

use this regex `\d+` for parse sections

Comment: I still get the whole ,111,222,333. Not sure if I was clear, I wanted separate matches for 111 another one for 222 and another for 333

Comment: i can change regex if you want get value from section1 only, if you want get values from all sections separately use regexes above

Comment: If I use your regex, I get a match like ",111,222,333," and I want to get captures as "111" then "222" then "333", not all of them in one group. I agree that your answer is generic, and if it works, I will accept the answer.

Comment: try this one `(?is)(?<=Section1.+?)(\d+)(?=,)(?=.+?Section2)`

Comment: Noob question - what does (?is) do?